# VB.net Redraw / Refresh / recalculate Chart

Tags: vb.net, charts, diagram

I guess there's tons of answers, but i have only found answers regarding the data update, not the chart itself.

In my case i have a chart that updates every X minutes. When the program starts, it looks in a file for some values. Lets say there's only one one value (one column in this case), and this value is 20. Then it shows it nice with 30 as maximum.

When it refresh, i do something like this

```
TheDiagram.Series.Clear()
Dim Serie_Value As New Series
With Serie_Value
    .Name = "MySerie"
    .ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn
    .Color = Color.Green
    With .Points
        .AddXY("MyName", theValueFromFile)
    End With
End With
TheDiagram.Series.Add(Serie_Value)
```

In this case, we say that the value now is 60, then the y-axis is still on 30 as max so that I can't see the end (top) of the column. 
How can I tell the chart/chartarea to "redraw yourself like you were rendered the first time"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried auto-scaling the y-axis?

```
' Auto axis scale
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.Minimum = [Double].NaN
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.Maximum = [Double].NaN
```

You should set those every time the chart refreshes, the axis should adjust automatically then.

Comment: Oh gee. This is an old topic that i've really forgotten about. I "fixed it" by deletering the old chartArea and create a new one for the new data, everytime it was reloaded. Every update could produce a very different layout, so i thougt that this solution would be the best. 
I did how ever try your code, and it works like a charm, and does exactly what i look for, so I'll accept that as the correct answer! :-)

Comment: This worked, since I couldn't trap out NaN for some reason.   With the Chart object, sometimes I think NaN can get loaded into the points, and the Overflow error occurs later when the NaN is alrady upstream (in the series).   With this fix, the error no longer occurs.

Answer (score 3):

To reset the auto scale just use this after loading the points into the chart.

```
Chart1.ResetAutoValues()
```

Answer (score 0):

Available since .NET 4.0: `Chart1.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();`